# Kafka Producer Quotas

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, messaging, throttling

Here is the inbound messaging flow in our IoT platform:

```
Device ---(MQTT)---> RabbitMQ Broker ---(AMQP)---> Apache Storm ---> Kafka
```

I'm looking to implement a solution which effectively limits/throttles the amount of data published to Kafka per second on a per-client basis.

The current strategy in place utilizes Guava's RateLimiter where each device gets its own locally cached instance. When a device message is received, the RateLimiter mapped to that deviceId is fetched from cache and the `tryAquire()` method is invoked. If a permit was successfully acquired then the tuple is forwarded to Kafka as usual, else, quota exceeded and message is discarded silently. This method is rather cumbersome and at some point doomed to fail or become a bottleneck.

I've been reading up on Kafka's byte-rate quotas and believe this would work perfectly in our case especially since Kafka clients can be configured dynamically. When a virtual device is created in our platform then a new client.id should be added where `client.id == deviceId`.

Let's assume the following use case as an example:

1. Admin creates 2 virtual devices: humidity & temp sensor
2. A rule is fired to create new user/clientId entries in Kafka for above devices
3. Set their producer quota values via Kafka CLI
4. Both devices emit an inbound event message
5. ...?

Here's my question. If using a single Producer instance, is it possible to specify a `client.id` in the ProducerRecord or somewhere in the Producer prior to calling `send()`? If a Producer is allowed only a single `client.id`, does this mean each device must have its own Producer? If only a one-to-one mapping is allowed then would it be wise to cache potentially hundreds, if not thousands, of Producer instances, one for each device? Is there a better approach I'm not aware of yet?

Note: Our platform is an "open door system" meaning clients never get sent back an error response such as "Rate Exceeded" or any error for that matter. It's all transparent to the end user. For this reason, I can't interfere with data in RabbitMQ or re-route messages to different queues.. my only option to integrate this stuff lies in between Storm or Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the `client.id` by application: `properties.put ("client.id", "humidity")` or `properties.put ("client.id", "temp")`
According to each `client.id` you can set the values

```
producer_byte_rate = 1024, consumer_byte_rate = 2048,
request_percentage = 200
```

A doubt that I am in relation to this configuration (`producer_byte_rate = 1024, consumer_byte_rate = 2048, request_percentage = 200`), the Producer does not assume the inserted configuration, since the Consumer is working properly

Answer (score 0):

While you can specify `client.id` on `Producer` object, remember that they are heavyweight, and you might not be willing to create multiple instances of them (especially on one-per-device basis).

Regarding reducing the number of `Producer`, have you considered creating one on a per-user, and not per-device basis, or even having a finite shared pool of them? Kafka message headers could then be used to discern which device actually produced the data. The drawback is that you would need to throttle message production on your side, so that one device does not grab all resources from the other ones.

However, you can limit the users on Kafka broker side, with configuration applying to default user/client:

```
> bin/kafka-configs.sh  --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --add-config 'producer_byte_rate=1024,consumer_byte_rate=2048,request_percentage=200' --entity-type clients --entity-default
Updated config for entity: default client-id.
```

See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas for more examples and explaination in depth.

How the messages are discerned depends on your architecture, the possible solutions include:

- a topic / partition per user (e.g. `data-USERABCDEF`)
- if you decide to use common topics, then you can put producer data into message headers - https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/common/header/Headers.html , or you can put them into payload itself

Comment: _"Kafka message headers could then be used to discern which device actually produced the data."_ Could you elaborate on this please and explain how to implement it? Even if I did it on a per user basis, I still need to figure out how to tell Kafka that message X originated from client 1, message Y originated from client 2, and so on.. all of which are being published via a **single**, shared Producer instance.